# Issue when converting to Mac with Apple's Catalyst

Tags: macos, codesign, macos-catalina, mac-catalyst

When I use Catalyst to try to create a Mac OS version of my iPad app I am getting the errors:

> "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code"

and

> "Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed"

I tried executing the terminal command `xattr -cr` on the product file inside the *"Debug-maccatalyst"* folder which is where the error line indicates that the bad data lies. This does not fix the problem.

Also, I do not experience any error when running the app on any version of the iPad.

I'm running Catalina Beta 4 and Xcode 11 beta 4.
Any insights or helpful suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Ok I have totally not tried this yet, but have you got one of the new Apple certificates? The old iOS or Mac certificate is not going to cut it when you go cross platform.

Comment: What do you mean by 'new' Apple certificates?

Comment: The ones with Apple in their name, new in Xcode 11.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will check it out.

Comment: As I say, I have not tried this. It's just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

i removed some jpgs and pngs i wasn't using from the project folder and now it works